# Content tree don't load / endless loop

Tags: horizon

I've installed `Sitecore 10.1` using installation guide steps. However, when I open `Horizon editor`, site pages don't load the content tree and the content editor keeps looping and refreshing. I see logs and it shows the following error: -

```
2022-03-24T12:47:46.2531303+11:00 [ERR] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) [Sitecore.FederatedUI.PageComposer] Error: Failed to get extension renderer for Horizon.Global.Search. Error: Failed to import: /global-search/main.js?v=10.1
    at d.<anonymous> (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/scripts/sitecore-composer.js:2:98583)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at a (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/scripts/sitecore-composer.js:2:97975)
    at c.invoke (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/client/polyfills.2b8588fcfa97b336d605.js:1:20491)
    at s.run (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/client/polyfills.2b8588fcfa97b336d605.js:1:15903)
    at https://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/client/polyfills.2b8588fcfa97b336d605.js:1:26835
    at c.invokeTask (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/client/polyfills.2b8588fcfa97b336d605.js:1:21109)
    at s.runTask (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/client/polyfills.2b8588fcfa97b336d605.js:1:16518)
    at y (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/client/polyfills.2b8588fcfa97b336d605.js:1:23103)
    at u.invokeTask [as invoke] (https://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/client/polyfills.2b8588fcfa97b336d605.js:1:22188)
2022-03-24T12:47:46.2537197+11:00 [INF] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Request finished in 8.2304ms 200 
2022-03-24T12:58:54.2058587+11:00 [INF] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://test-horizon101-ext.com/horizon/api application/json 253
2022-03-24T12:58:54.2068200+11:00 [INF] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Policy execution successful.
2022-03-24T12:58:54.2771658+11:00 [ERR] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Error processing GraphQL query
GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve components. ---> System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: language
   at Sitecore.Horizon.API.Gateway.ContentApiClient.SSC.SscContentApiClient.GetComponentsAsync(String language, String site)
   at Sitecore.Horizon.API.Gateway.Schema.Queries.HorizonComponentQueries.GetComponentList(ResolveFieldContext`1 context)
   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteNodeAsync(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2022-03-24T12:58:54.3493445+11:00 [INF] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Request finished in 143.5269ms 200 application/json
2022-03-24T12:58:56.2087461+11:00 [INF] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://vvic-test-horizon101-ext.akqa.net.au/horizon/api application/json 253
2022-03-24T12:58:56.2105952+11:00 [INF] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Policy execution successful.
2022-03-24T12:58:56.2119653+11:00 [ERR] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Error processing GraphQL query
GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve components. ---> System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: language
   at Sitecore.Horizon.API.Gateway.ContentApiClient.SSC.SscContentApiClient.GetComponentsAsync(String language, String site)
   at Sitecore.Horizon.API.Gateway.Schema.Queries.HorizonComponentQueries.GetComponentList(ResolveFieldContext`1 context)
   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteNodeAsync(ExecutionContext context, ExecutionNode node)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2022-03-24T12:58:56.2140848+11:00 [INF] (Sitecore Authoring Host/SitecoreTest) Request finished in 5.5929ms 200 application/json
```

Comment: how did you resolve it please let me know thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `Sitecore 10+` for `horizon` to work. You need to install the below mentioned module : -

`HEADLESS_VERSION=18.0.0-1809`.

Best Regards,
Sanjay

Comment: Hi Sanjay, don't think that's the pre-requisite. I've installed Horizon on vanilla SC10.1.2 instance and Horizon works without installing Headless module. The error I posted is from our Test environment where we've custom solution in place. I've raised support ticket with Sitecore nonetheless so will see how it goes, but definitely Headless module is not required to be installed.

Comment: I am using SXA and Jss for that we need headless for Horizon to work.